# Wake up my monitor when I start my computer

Tags: windows-10, display, hdmi, wake-up

When I start my Raspberry PI or Xbox and they are connected in HDMI to my monitor, they automatically turn on my monitor via the HDMI cable.

I wanted to know if it was possible to do the same with my computer?
I wish that when I turn on my computer, it sends the signal to 
my monitor to turn it on.

Be indulgent, I'm new in the forum and my English is approximate.
Thanks

In this computer I have Windows 10, GC : Nvidia GTX 1060 6GB, my motherboard: Gigabyte GA-Z170-Gaming-K3-EU rev1.1, proc : Intel Core i5-6600K

Edit: If there is no parameter for turn on my monitor with hdmi cable on a pc, did you know a soft for that or this is not possible on a computer ?

Comment: What connection are your currently using? DP, HDMI or VGA?

Comment: Or DVI-I/DVI-D?

Comment: I've say HDMI in my question @Seth

Comment: You said you connect your Raspberry Pi and Xbox that way. You didn't say whenever or not your PC is also using that connection. Do you turn off your display entirely or put it in standby? What display is it?

Comment: My display is in standby, it's a TV. I read that raspberry pi turn on the TV because it send a signal on pin 12, is it possible with a computer or the graphics card doesn't support this ?

Comment: no one can answer me?